# Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, usestate

Hola estoy intentando crear un header donde cuanto el mouse entre a una categoria se desplieguen mas categorias el problema es que me aparece este mensaje

Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
y no se por que aparezca dejo aqui mi codigo

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Header = () => {
    const [getMensaje, setMensaje] = useState();
    const caffe = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        const coffee = caffe.current 
        if(coffee){
            coffee.insertAdjacentText("beforeend", getMensaje)
        }
    },[getMensaje])

        return(<header className="header">
        <div className="container_img">
            <NavLink to="/">
                <img src="https://www.starbucks.com.mx/media/logo_tcm54-366_w1024_n.png" alt="starbucks" />
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div className="container_li">
            <nav>
                <div className="div_nosirve">
                    <span>< NavLink to="/cafee" ref={caffe} onMouseEnter={setMensaje("Hola mi amigo")} className="header_li">CAFE</NavLink></span>
                    <span><NavLink to="/menu-list"  className="header_li">MENU</NavLink></span>
                    <span><NavLink to="/coffeehouse"  className="header_li"> TIENDAS</NavLink></span>
                    <span><NavLink to="/responsibility"  className="header_li"> IMPACTO SOCIAL</NavLink></span>
                    <span><NavLink to="/about-us"  className="header_li"> STARBUCKS</NavLink></span>
                    <span><NavLink to="/loyalty"   className="header_li">STARBUCKS REWARDS</NavLink></span>
                    <span><NavLink to="/blog/covid-19_buenas_cosas_estan_pasando"   className="header_li">BLOG</NavLink></span>
                    <span><NavLink to="/historiasstarbucks" className="header_li">HISTORIAS STARBUCKS</NavLink></span>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>)
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

tu problema está en la prop onMouseEnter:

```
onMouseEnter={setMensaje("Hola mi amigo")}
```

Debería ser así:

```
onMouseEnter={() => setMensaje("Hola mi amigo")}
```

De lo contrarío, la función se ejecuta constantemente, y por eso está causando que el componente entre en un loop.